# Integrating loading images with jQuery and Google Visualization

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

I'm currently working on an inherited project which uses Google's Visualization API (for both Python and Javascript). Since parsing the data for Gviz takes a while, I'm trying to let the page fetch a [loading image](http://www.ajaxload.info/) and display it while the relevant charts are loading via AJAX calls.

While I could be wrong, I believe that I have been coding it correctly; below you can find the relevant code, which I have inserted into the `<head>` portion of the page.

```
$(function() {
    var dates = $("#from, #to").datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        beforeShow: function() {
            var other = this.id == "from" ? "#to" : "#from";
            var option = this.id == "from" ? "maxDate" : "minDate";
            var selectedDate = $(other).datepicker('getDate');
            $(this).datepicker("option", option, selectedDate);
        },
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            drawCharts();
        }
    }).change(function() {
        var other = this.id == "from" ? "#to" : "#from";
        if ($('#from').datepicker('getDate') > $('#to').datepicker('getDate'))
            $(other).datepicker('setDate', $(this).datepicker('getDate'));
    });
    $("#from").datepicker("setDate", '-13');
    $("#to").datepicker("setDate", new Date());

    $("#weekly_cohorts").click(function() {
        weekly = true;
        drawCharts();
    });

    $("#monthly_cohorts").click(function() {
        weekly = false;
        drawCharts();
    });

    // ERROR OCCURS HERE
    google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['corechart', 'table']});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(getData);
});
```

<strike>When I run this, Chrome's JavaScript Console displays an error message along the lines of `EVENT FIRED TOO FAST`, which doesn't make sense to me according to the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3).</strike>

If I call the two lines earlier (i.e., outside of the `$( handler )`), however, I have no problems, but the preloading image isn't fetched until it's too late.

<strike>What's going wrong, and how do I fix it?</strike> While I could just move the script to the end of the body, I prefer to have all my stylesheet and script references in the head.

**EDIT:** Chrome's console no longer gives me that error, but since the page doesn't fully render before the script is called, it can't interact with the DOM. In addition, the image is still not fetched until after script execution.

Again, any ideas on how to delay script execution (triggered by the second line) from the DOMContent event to the Load event (i.e., until the page is fully rendered)?

**EDIT 2:** I *briefly* managed to get it to work as desired, but only after I restarted Chrome. However, I believe that was only because it was already stored in the local cache (i.e., HTTP Response code 304), since refreshing the page only brought back the "page not rendering before script is called" problem.

Comment: I don't get what you mean by 'image'. Do you mean you're trying to load an image of a chart while it renders the js? Or do you just mean loading the gviz javascript libraries? If you could elaborate, that would help.

Comment: @oli Thanks for pointing that out; I have amended the question to specify the image I want to load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** Put your call to `google.load()` in an img onload handler.  Do not use jQuery for this, as the img may have already loaded by the time the `ready` handler is called.

```
<img src="loading.gif" onload="loadCharts()" />
```

```
function loadCharts () {
    google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['corechart', 'table']}); 
    google.setOnLoadCallback(getData); 
}
```

---

Original answer:

Is `getData()` your intended onload handler?  Or does it return a function that you want to use as the onload handler?  If it is itself the onload handler, remove the parentheses so as to return a function reference, rather than immediately calling the function:

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(getData);
```

But, if `getData()` does indeed itself return a function, and you need to delay your code execution until after the page has loaded, bind to the `window.onload` event:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    ...
});
```

Instead of `document.ready` (`$(function () { ... })`).

Comment: It doesn't return a function; it's the onload handler. I already removed the `()` caller; I'll try the second suggestion, though.

Comment: Forgot I already tried that; all it does is briefly render the page before hiding everything - and it doesn't execute the script at all.

Comment: Thank you! It now yields a `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onload' of null`, but I couldn't give a shit so long as my visualizations are working.